# Rendering while cycling through object isn't working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object

```
arrangement: {
        'A': [{'1': 1}, {'2': 0}, {'3': 1}, {'4': 1}, {'5': 1}, {'6': 0}, {'7': 1}],
        'B': [{'1': 1}, {'2': 1}, {'3': 0}, {'4': 1}, {'5': 1}, {'6': 1}, {'7': 1}, {'8': 1}],
        'C': [{'1': 1}, {'2': 0}, {'3': 0}, {'4': 1}, {'5': 0}, {'6': 0}, {'7': 0}, {'8': 1}, {'9': 0}],
        'D': [{'1': 0}, {'2': 0}, {'3': 1}, {'4': 0}, {'5': 1}, {'6': 0}, {'7': 0}, {'8': 1}, {'9': 0}],
        'E': [{'1': 1}, {'2': 1}, {'3': 1}, {'4': 0}, {'5': 0}, {'6': 1}, {'7': 1}, {'8': 1}, {'9': 0}],
        'F': [{'1': 0}, {'2': 0}, {'3': 0}, {'4': 0}, {'5': 1}, {'6': 0}, {'7': 1}, {'8': 0}, {'9': 0}],
        'G': [{'1': 1}, {'2': 1}, {'3': 1}, {'4': 1}, {'5': 1}, {'6': 1}, {'7': 1}, {'8': 1}, {'9': 1}],
      }
```

and I want to generate a div for every part of A,B,D,... There are cinema rows with seats, so div for every row, and inside them small divs for every seat: 0: free, 1:occupied.
I have tried using Object keys, then mapping, and then after all mapping every row like that, but it didnt work, saying "Objects are not valid as a React child", but i have no clue how to fix it them.
Any ideas?

```
let seatMap = Object.keys(seats).map(row => (
            <div>
                <p>{row}</p>
                {
                    seats[row].map(seat => (
                        <div className="seat">{seat}</div>
                    ))
                }
            </div>
```

Comment: `seat` will be an object. You probably need to get `Object.entries(seat)` to get the key and the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on evolutionxbox comment, you can access seat number using the index:

```
let seatMap = Object.keys(seats).map(row => (
            <div>
                <p>{row}</p>
                {
                    seats[row].map((seat, index) => (
                        <div className="seat">{seat[index+1]}</div>
                    ))
                }
            </div>
```

Comment: How I get it, thank you very much. Ofc working perfectly

Answer (score 1):

The error you're given is because you are trying to render an object as a jsx child (`seat`), which is something you cannot do.

Here is how you can create a div for each property of each seat:

```js
Object.keys(seats).map(row => (
  <div>
    <p>{row}</p>
    {seats[row].map(seat => Object.keys(seat).map(seatProperty => (
      <div className="seat">{seatProperty}</div>
    )))}
  </div>
))
```

Comment: I have used Hyetigran's solution, as its more comfortable for me. However, thank you for the answer

Answer (score 1):

**Working Example: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-migspn?file=src%2FApp.js)**

[image]

```js
import React from "react";
import "./style.css";
let arrangement = {
        'A': [{'1': 1}, {'2': 0}, {'3': 1}, {'4': 1}, {'5': 1}, {'6': 0}, {'7': 1}],
        'B': [{'1': 1}, {'2': 1}, {'3': 0}, {'4': 1}, {'5': 1}, {'6': 1}, {'7': 1}, {'8': 1}],
        'C': [{'1': 1}, {'2': 0}, {'3': 0}, {'4': 1}, {'5': 0}, {'6': 0}, {'7': 0}, {'8': 1}, {'9': 0}],
        'D': [{'1': 0}, {'2': 0}, {'3': 1}, {'4': 0}, {'5': 1}, {'6': 0}, {'7': 0}, {'8': 1}, {'9': 0}],
        'E': [{'1': 1}, {'2': 1}, {'3': 1}, {'4': 0}, {'5': 0}, {'6': 1}, {'7': 1}, {'8': 1}, {'9': 0}],
        'F': [{'1': 0}, {'2': 0}, {'3': 0}, {'4': 0}, {'5': 1}, {'6': 0}, {'7': 1}, {'8': 0}, {'9': 0}],
        'G': [{'1': 1}, {'2': 1}, {'3': 1}, {'4': 1}, {'5': 1}, {'6': 1}, {'7': 1}, {'8': 1}, {'9': 1}],
      };



export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Seating arrangement</h1>
      {Object.keys(arrangement).map(key => {
        let row = arrangement[key];
        return (
          <div style={styles.main}>
            <p>{key} row: </p>
            {row.map((obj, index) => (
              <div
                style={{
                  ...styles.row,
                  backgroundColor: Object.values(obj)[0] ? "green" : "red"
                }}
              />
            ))}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

const styles = {
  main: {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  row: {
    width: 10,
    height: 10,
    borderRadius: 5,
    marginRight: 2
  }
};
```